# IE issue with Ennui Jquery Content Slider, doesn't center content

Tags: jquery, css, slider

A demo of the slider i'm using can be found here: http://www.copterlabs.com/demo/contentslider/

My page with the slider is here: http://crucialexams.com/test/test-exam-1

The issue is, in IE, the first page doesn't center, rather it has a large space to the left of it.  After using the arrows to navigate back/forth everything works just as it should.  I have this problem in all IE's that I have used.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

FIXED:
Depending on how the php worked out, it sometimes wasn't putting a starting html tag.  Fixed it, and it centers fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it in both IE7/8 and it was centered. Did you update since you posted?

Comment: Here is what i'm seeing, http://i.filebin.org/fGjtQ on IE9, I don't have IE8 on this computer but I've used it at work with the same issue.  Thanks for the response

Comment: It sometimes wasn't putting an html tag in, I fixed it.  Thanks for your time!